# Div sized based on sibling's size

Tags: css, layout, flexbox

I'd like to be able to dynamically set the height of a `div` (let's call it `#div1`) based on the height of its sibling (`#div2`), if it's possible. `#div2` will be resized using JavaScript, but I'd like it if the size of `#div1` could be changed automagically. The parent div would resize as well, based on the size of its two children (`#div1` and `#div2`).

I've tried using CSS flexbox for this, and gotten very close. Say I want to make sure that `#div1` is 20% of the height of `#div2`. I can apply `display: flex; flex-direction: column` to the parent, give `#div2` `flex-grow: 5` and give `flex-grow: 1` to `#div1`. This works nicely, and does almost exactly what I want.

I need a way to use this flexbox layout, but I need the layout to work based on the size of the sibling, not the size of the parent. My solution (https://jsfiddle.net/pg3b9n6h/1/) requires the parent size to be set, while I want both the parent and the sibling to update based on a size change in `#div2`.

Is this possible?

Comment: don't think that is possible without setting the parent div size, but I guess there is a way to adjust parent div and sibliing div to match the div height along the cross-axis - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545915/css-limit-the-height-from-scroll-dynamically/39546076#39546076)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is :), here's how:

```js
function changeHeight(amount){
  const subStyle = document.querySelector('.main .sub').style;
  subStyle.height = parseInt(subStyle.height, 10) + amount + 'px';
}
```

```css
.main {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
.sub {
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.sub2 {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button onclick='changeHeight(100)'>+100px</button>
<button onclick='changeHeight(-100)'>-100px</button>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sub" style='height: 100px'></div>
  <div class="sub2"></div>
</div>
```

Edit: if anyone downvotes me, please explain why so I can learn from it!

Comment: Thanks. I think this is downvoted because the question asked about a CSS-only solution. This is definitely useful though.