# Make height of a row of CSS flexbox containers be height of a specific container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to have a flexbox implementation of a single row of containers have an overall height equal to a specific container's height? My current basic CSS implementation is:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}
```

With the following HTML:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="left-container">
    stuff
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    some other stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, `.right-container` can get really tall, height wise. So I want to constrain `.flex-container` to be the height of `.left-container`, whatever height it ends up being (which I don't know ahead of time). In this way, `.right-container` ends up having a scrollbar.

So is this possible via CSS only, or will I need Javascript for this? If it helps, I don't necessarily have to use flexbox here, but I found it the most convenient to use in my application except for this height issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to set a `max-height` on them? And just set `height: 100%;` -> it will never exceed the `max-height` you set?

Comment: I thought about using `max-height`, but I really don't know how much space `.left-container` will take. There's actually a large range of heights it can take. All I know is, I never want that container to have a scrollbar. My `.right-container` can be much, much taller, which is my need for constraint. If I see no other solution, then I may just have to set some conservative `max-height` value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS: limit the height from scroll dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545915/css-limit-the-height-from-scroll-dynamically)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}

.left-container{
  background-color:red;
  }
.right-container{
  background-color:green;
  }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="left-container">
    stuff
  </div>
  <div class="right-container">
    some other stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you set the height of the 3 elements and set `overflow-y` to `scroll` on the `.left-container`, that should do the trick.

```css
.flex-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      align-items: stretch;
      border: solid 1px grey;
      padding: 5px;
  height: 150px;
    }

    .left-container {
      border: solid 1px red;
      flex: 1;
      height: 150px;
    }

    .right-container {
      border: solid 1px blue;
        flex: 3;
      height: 150px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
      <div class="left-container">
        stuff
      </div>
      <div class="right-container">
        some other stuff some other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuffsome other stuff
      </div>
    </div>
```